# Facebook Redirect URI field not showing

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, facebook-login

I keep getting the following message in Facebook, however there is no input field for me to meet the requirement they are asking for. I believe this issue is causing my app to fail.
[image]

Comment: It’s under Products -> Facebook Login now.

Comment: Thanks I just noticed that after reading a source coast thread!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt see this til reading another thread from another site. But you must add a product. Then configure that product.[image]